# wwwroot not always updating on Azure Webapp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have accessed my site via Kudu @ my-site.scm.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot/

I've noticed that the files in webroot are not the most up-to-date.
I am updating the site via github and Azure CLI.
My repo is hosting the correct files.

When I SSH on the Linux server, and `cat <updated file>`, it is up-to-date and reflective of the files in my repo.

How do I update the wwwroot?

Comment: Please share screenshots of the contents of the files under wwwroot, and inform which files have not been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly stopping and then re-starting the webapp if "Restart" from the management portal did not solve the issue.

Possible cause: Azure App Service Deploy task version

Make sure you have the latest. linux azure app service is different from windows azure app service. Linux app service don't have default so you need to set. So follow the steps below:

```
Use WebDeploy/MSDeploy to deploy my web app. You need to set an app setting called WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM to false.
```

OR

```
When the Select deployment method option is not checked, the task appears to prefer the Run From Package option. The solution for us now isto select the option and choose Web Deploy as our deployment method.
```

If Git deployment fails to your Linux web app, choose one of the following options to deploy your application code:

- Use the Continuous Delivery (Preview) feature: You can store your
  app's source code in an Azure DevOps Git repo or GitHub repo to use
  Azure Continuous Delivery. For more information, see How to configure
  Continuous Delivery for Linux web app.
- Use the ZIP deploy API ([refer](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4/README.md#deployment)): To use this API, SSH into your web app and go
  to the folder where you want to deploy your code. Run the following
  code:

> curl -X POST -u  --data-binary @
> https://{your-sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy

If you get an error that the curl command is not found, make sure you install curl by using apt-get install curl before you run the previous curl command.

> You'll need to specify a startup script for the type of app you are
> running.

[image]

[Download](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) Azure Storage Explorer, free tool to conveniently manage your Azure cloud storage resources from your desktop. (also to virtual web app directories)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, as there is no way to know what is happening with the OP's issue (not enough detail). What you provided here is more of a troubleshooting guide.